# Replicate/Sync a folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, sync, replication

I have a folder located at `E:\My Work\code_library` which I plan to store code snippets, etc..

I have a folder located at `E:\Server\htdocs\code_library` which is my Apache root directory

Is there a way that I can edit files at either location and have them replicate/stay in sync/ or BE the same files?

For organizational purposes, I would like to keep files located at `E:\My Work\code_library` this folder has a large amount of other folders, all work related, it is easy to copy/transport/keep on a thumb drive/etc... these files as they are all located in a convenient location TOGETHER

I then have to keep files at `E:\Server\htdocs\code_library` as well so I can access them in my web browser and have PHP and stuff work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are comfortable with the command line, you can make a symbolic link in `htdocs` that points to `E:\My Work\code_library`.

Remove/rename the `code_library` directory in `E:\Server\htdocs`. Then open a command prompt, and CD to `E:\Server\htdocs`. Then make your symbolic link:

```
mklink /d code_library "E:\My Work\code_library"
```

I should mention that you can do this the other way. That is, leave the Apache folder `code_library` in place, and make `E:\My Work\code_library` a symbolic link that points to the Apache copy.

Comment: This looks like it could be a good solution, Ill research it more, thank you

Comment: I actually do this with my Visual Studio project folder. Not with Apache, but because I like having it in a root folder called Work. Visual Studio likes me to have a folder called Projects in My Documents. So a make a Projects symlink that points to \Work.

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't aware of this feature.  Lately I have really been organizing things to optimize my work-flow in future projects and this looks like a really useful thing for multiple things.  I am curious, do you know if there is a way to save this to some sort of file that can be ran.  For example, if I format my drives or got a new PC, would be nice to be able to double click a file to restore symlinks?

Comment: symlinks are part of the filesystem.  You don't need to "save" them, they're already on the drive.  Now, if you're talking about symlinks across drive boundaries, then you'd need a backup utility that's aware of them.

Comment: I agree with afrazier. You could also save the mklink command line above to a batch file, and run that if you completely rebuild the system.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question in this [SU post](https://superuser.com/questions/353811/does-rsync-require-2-computers). If you are ok with manually triggering the sync operation, [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155), a free PowerToy utility from Microsoft, may provide the functionality that you're looking for. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy), operations include:

> - **Synchronize** takes the two folders and makes sure they have exactly the same files. To do this, SyncToy may copy files in either
>     direction and may delete or rename files in either folder. In the case
>     that a file has been updated in both the left and right folders, the
>     version with the later modification date is considered the conflict
>     winner and will overwrite the other version.[3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy)
> - **Echo** looks for changes (file modifications, new files, renames, deletes) in the left folder and makes them in the right folder
>     (one-way sync).
> - **Contribute** is like an Echo, but it does not delete any files on the right folder that may have been deleted in the left folder.