# Does rsync require 2 computers?

Tags: windows-7, sync, rsync

I am wanting to use something like rsync (i think).  I am using Windows 7, I would like to be able to sync files/folder to other Disks on 1 computer, sometimes, just keep 2 folders or more in sync on the same drive even, and sometimes onto seperate drives.

Is RSYNC only used for when there is a client computer and a server computer?  Or can it be used to sync files on the same computer?

Is RSYNC is not what I am looking for, please suggest the best alternative for Windows 7.  I know there is a lot of similar post, but most recommend rsync and I think it may not be what is needed for what I describe above?

One example of a use, Let's say I have a folder,

`E:\Thumb_Drive` which is on my PC and then I have a USB drive at

`G:\Thumb_Drive` and I would like to be able to edit the contents of **EITHER folder** and have them stay in sync

Answer (score 3):

I'm aware there are rsync clients for Windows, however not having used them, I cannot comment on their specific functionality. However, if they emulate even closely what rsync does on *nix, then yes, you can rsync between folders on a single host. While there are certainly other, and some may argue better, methods to achieve this task, rsync is indeed a good tool to use.

I use it daily in a Linux environment and in fact the vast majority of the time I do so syncing files between disks on a single host (computer).

Answer (score 1):

`rsync` can be used between two locations on the same computer. You should restrict the bandwidth it uses though (with `--bwlimit`), or it will drive the performance of the rest of your system into the ground.

You will want to look at something else though ([Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/)?), since it does not handle two-way synchronization well on its own.

Answer (score 1):

rsync works very well on a single computer in *nix systems. For Windows, Microsoft has a free utility ([SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=15155)) that provides similar functionality with a graphical interface. I've used it frequently at work to keep two separate folders in sync - you can choose to keep everything in sync (including deletes) or to sync updates only. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SyncToy):

> - **Synchronize** takes the two folders and makes sure they have exactly the same files. To do this, SyncToy may copy files in either
>     direction and may delete or rename files in either folder. In the case
>     that a file has been updated in both the left and right folders, the
>     version with the later modification date is considered the conflict
>     winner and will overwrite the other version.[3]
> - **Echo** looks for changes (file modifications, new files, renames, deletes) in the left folder and makes them in the right folder
>     (one-way sync).
> - **Contribute** is like an Echo, but it does not delete any files on the right folder that may have been deleted in the left folder.